# Efficiently reformat column entries in large data set in R

Tags: r

I have a large (6 million row) table of values that I believe needs to be reformatted before it can be used for comparison to my data set. The table has 3 columns that I care about. 
The first column contains nucleotide base changes, in the form of C>G, A>C, A>G, etc. I'd like to split these into two separate columns. 
The second column has the chromosome and base position, formatted as 10:130448, 2:40483, 5:30821291, etc. I would also like to split this into two columns.
The third column has the allelic fraction in a number of sample populations, formatted like .02/.03/.20. I'd like to extract the third fraction into a new column.

The problem is that the code I have written is currently extremely slow. It looks like it will take about a day and a half just to run. Is there something I'm missing here? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

My current code does the following: pos, change, and fraction each receive a vector of the above values split use strsplit. I then loop through the entire database, getting the ith value from those three vectors, and creating new columns with the values I want.

Once the database has been formatted, I should be able to easily check a large number of samples by chromosome number, base, reference allele, alternate allele, etc.

```
pos <- strsplit(total.esp$NCBI.Base, ":")
change <- strsplit(total.esp$Alleles, ">")
fraction <- strsplit(total.esp$'MAFinPercent(EA/AA/All)', "/")
for (i in 1:length(pos)){
    current <- pos[[i]]
    mutation <- change[[i]]
    af <- fraction[[i]]
    total.esp$chrom[i] <- current[1]
    total.esp$base[i] <- current [2]
    total.esp$ref[i] <- mutation[1]
    total.esp$alt[i] <- mutation[2]
    total.esp$af[i] <- af[3]

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (after retaining your first three lines of code):

```
 total.esp   <- data.frame( chrom =sapply( pos, "[", 1), 
                            base = sapply( pos, "[", 2), 
                            ref  = sapply( change, "[", 1), 
                            alt = sapply(change, "[", 2), 
                            af  = sapply( af,  "[", 3)
                           )
```

I cannot imagine this taking more than a couple of minutes. (I do work with R objects of similar size.)

Comment: data.table 1.9.6 has an efficient tstrsplit function if that could help. for loops in R are often not a good idea. see e.g. this: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html [scroll down].

Comment: Took about 40 seconds! Thanks so much. I didn't realize brackets could be used as a function

Comment: Yes. Discovering that `[`, `[[`, `~`, and `$` were all really functions "under the hood" was incrementally surprising to me as well. They can all be written as (and are actually parsed-to) internal forms like `"["(dat, row,col)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tidyr`, `dplyr` and `separate`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

total.esp %>% separate(Alleles, c("ref", "alt"), sep=">") %>% 
              separate(NCBI.Base, c("chrom", "base"), sep=":") %>%
              separate(MAFinPercent.EA.AA.All., c("af1", "af2", "af3"), sep="/") %>%
              select(-af1, -af2, af = af3)
```

You'll need to be careful about that last `MAFinPercent.EA.AA.All.` - you have a horrible column name so may have to rename it/quote it depending on how exactly r has it (this is also a good reason to include at least some data in your question, such as the output of `dput(head(total.esp))`).

data used to check:

```
total.esp <- data.frame(Alleles= rep("C>G", 50), NCBI.Base = rep("10:130448", 50), 'MAFinPercent(EA/AA/All)'= rep(".02/.03/.20", 50))
```

---

Because we now have a `tidyr/dplyr` solution, a `data.table` solution and a base solution, let's benchmark them. First, data from @akrun, 300,000 rows in total:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Alleles =rep(c('C>G', 'A>C', 'A>G'), 100000),
                  NCBI.Base=rep(c('10:130448', '2:40483', '5:30821291'),  100000),
                  MAFinPercent= rep(c('.02/.03/.20', '.05/.03/.04', '.02/.04/.03'),  100000),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now, the benchmark:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  tidyr = {df1 %>% separate(Alleles, c("ref", "alt"), sep=">") %>% 
                   separate(NCBI.Base, c("chrom", "base"), sep=":") %>%
                   separate(MAFinPercent, c("af1", "af2", "af3"), sep="/") %>%
                   select(-af1, -af2, af = af3)},
  data.table = {setDT(df1)[, unlist(lapply(.SD, tstrsplit,
                                           split='[>:/]', type.convert=TRUE), recursive=FALSE)]},
  base = {pos <- strsplit(df1$NCBI.Base, ":");
          change <- strsplit(df1$Alleles, ">");
          fraction <- strsplit(df1$MAFinPercent, "/");
          data.frame( chrom =sapply( pos, "[", 1), 
                      base = sapply( pos, "[", 2), 
                      ref  = sapply( change, "[", 1), 
                      alt = sapply(change, "[", 2), 
                      af  = sapply( fraction,  "[", 3)
          )}
)
Unit: seconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
      tidyr 1.295970 1.398792 1.514862 1.470185 1.629978 1.889703   100
 data.table 2.140007 2.209656 2.315608 2.249883 2.481336 2.666345   100
       base 2.718375 3.079861 3.183766 3.154202 3.221133 3.791544   100
```

`tidyr` is the winner

Comment: I think on a big dataset, data.table should be faster.  The 30,000 rows is not a very big one.

Comment: I was surprised too - feel free to edit if you run a larger benchmark

Comment: I am trying on a slightly bigger dataset.

Comment: I still have tidyr winning at 300,000

Comment: 1. It's important to verify that the results are identical in benchmarks. Akrun has used `type.convert=TRUE`.  2. The major reason for difference is that you're using a simpler pattern and repeating the `separate()` for every column (not really generic). If I do the same as yours with `tstrsplit()` on each column with `fixed=TRUE` on 300,000 rows, it takes 0.27s (tidyr = 1.1s).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll make sure to include a head() call next time I have a data frame related question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `data.table` solution.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), loop over the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) with `lapply`, use `tstrsplit` and `split` the columns by specifying the split character, `unlist` the output with `recursive=FALSE`.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(df1)[, unlist(lapply(.SD, tstrsplit,
        split='[>:/]', type.convert=TRUE), recursive=FALSE)]
#   Alleles1 Alleles2 NCBI.Base1 NCBI.Base2 MAFinPercent1 MAFinPercent2
#1:        C        G         10     130448          0.02          0.03
#2:        A        C          2      40483          0.05          0.03
#3:        A        G          5   30821291          0.02          0.04
#   MAFinPercent3
#1:          0.20
#2:          0.04
#3:          0.03
```

NOTE: I assumed that there are only 3 columns in the dataset.  If there are more columns, and want to do the split only for the 3 columns, we can specify the `.SDcols= 1:3` i.e. column index or the actual column names, assign (`:=`) the output to new columns and subset the columns that are only needed in the output.

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Alleles =c('C>G', 'A>C', 'A>G'), 
   NCBI.Base=c('10:130448', '2:40483', '5:30821291'), 
   MAFinPercent= c('.02/.03/.20', '.05/.03/.04', '.02/.04/.03'), 
   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```